# Products take 2-5 minutes to appear on site

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am working in a Sitecore Commerce 10. When I add a new product to the catalog, I can only see the new products after 2-5 minutes on the published site. Is there any way to reduce the time it takes to display the products on published site?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because of caching policy of Sellable items.
Go to `PlugIn.Caching.PolicySet-1.0.0.json` `(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring\wwwroot\data\Environments)`, open it and search for `SellableItem`, you will notice it has `Expiration` set to `7200000`, which is in milliseconds that means `120 minutes or 2 hours`, try to reduce it and then do `Bootstrap` and check.

```
      {
        "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.EntityCachingPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
        "EntityFullName": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.SellableItem",
        "AllowCaching": true,
        "Priority": "Normal",
        "Expiration": 7200000,
        "HasNegativeCaching": true,
        "CacheName": "SellableItems",
        "EntityIdPrefix": "Entity-SellableItem"
      },
```